# builtin function or method object is not iterable

Tags: python, for-loop, iteration, jupyter-notebook, python-3.7

I'm new to Python and stackoverflow too. I'm trying to write a program that can differentiate between odd nums and even nums but I'm getting this err. Help!. This is my prog:

```
print("Enter the 10 numbers separated by space to distinguish : ")
string1 = str(input())
if len(string1) == 10 or 20:
    list1 = string1.split
    for num in list1:
        #check for odd
        if num % 2 == 0 :
            print(num)
        else:
            print(f'Odd number : {num}')
else:
    print("Please enter 10 numbers")
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: You forgot to use the brackets `()` after `split`. What happens if you use this?
`list1 = string1.split(' ')`

Comment: `input` already returns a string, no need to call `str` on it.

Comment: There are more things in the script that won't work. I will help if you focus on datatypes (int, string, float, etc.). Every time you get an error, check the datatype and the action you want to perform

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems in this code:

- `string1 = str(input())` `input` already returns a string, no need to call `str`
- `list1 = string1.split` You forgot `()` to actually call the `split` method.
- `if len(string1) == 10 or 20:` does not do what you think it does. It will always evaluate to `True` since it is interpreted as `(len(string1) == 10) or 20`. You want `len(string1) in (10, 20)`
- `num % 2 == 0` `num` will be a string here, you want `int(num) % 2 == 0`.